# Is there a library in plain C that converts GPX to KML, and other geo-formats?

Tags: c, geospatial

Is there a library in plain C that converts GPX to KML, and other geo-formats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/download.html) supports GPX and KML, I *think* it is written in C, but I've never had occasion to check.

Update: Looks like it is written in C. Just downloaded the source from the [Debian packages site](http://packages.debian.org/sid/gpsbabel) and it's chock full of .c and .h files.

Comment: Thanks... this is the answer. But in the words of Jamie Zawinsky - now I have two problems.

Comment: I use it in open-source Geocaching app GPSTurbo, it's great!